# deploying my django site to windows server without using IIS

Tags: python, django, deployment, windows-server

I finished writing a Django application and now I want to deploy it,

I have a Windows server and have successfully installed Python and Django on it,

Now my app runs on localhost on my windows server,

Now I want to make the site public, meaning that anyone who goes to the IP address of my windows server can browse my site,

Is there a simple way to do this without using IIS?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

### Step One

Set a static ip for your server (It's possible without this, but easier)

Once set, log into your router as admin, and forward port `80` to your servers ip address.
There is a tutorial for this at https://portforward.com

### Step Two

#### If you already have a domain name, ignore this bit

Purchase a domain name from an domain name from a domain name registrar such as

1and1 / Ionos (https://ionos.com)

(I would personally advise against https://GoDaddy.com, the prices tend to be odd there)

#### Step 2.1

Go into your domains settings, and forward traffic to the external ip address of your router.

Hope that this helped!

Comment: first of all - thanks! 
I followed guide for setting static ip and i should set  alternate DNS server address
what this mean?
do I have to set specific DNS?
can you help me with this?
thank you again

Comment: You need to set the DNS to your routers dns. I should have included this, but you need to figure out your routers dns. You can do this by running `ipconfig /all` on a windows computer connected to the network. Then find the DNS the command returns, and set your servers DNS to that.

Answer (score 0):

I've never done what your planing but if you plan to host just one domain then localhost(127.0.0.1) will work just fine but if you plane to host multiple domain you will need to find a way to resolve the right domain to the right site.

Ports to open on both router and Win Server
80 for HTTP
465 for HTTPS

Make sure that you have a Static IP provided by your ISP, you will also need to make sure that your ISP does not Block port 80 if they do ask them to unblock.

If you don't have a static IP or ISP don't allow you to open port 80 then you can use DynDNS to forward traffic to your server, but this option is not the best.

Your Server will also need a static IP to the server as mentiond by Legorooj